# Digitally sign HTML-form using hwcrypto

Tags: javascript, cryptojs, pkcs#11, cmdb

I'm looking for a way to digitally sign an HTML-form with PKCS#11 (smart card) with [hwcrypto](https://github.com/hwcrypto/hwcrypto.js/wiki/ModernAPI).

Context: at our company we use [Combodo's iTop](https://www.combodo.com/itop-193) as CMDB. Company devices need to be registered and the employee needs to sign a proof of loan. I like to make this proof digitally. Since we use full PKI enabled company cards, employees can sign these proof digitally with their card (and pin). 
I've written a simple [plugin for iTop](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=2_4_0%3Acustomization%3Aadd-menu-sample) to generate a proof (PDF) prefilled for the device. But when I want to save the signed PDF back to iTop (via [REST API](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=2_2_0%3Aadvancedtopics%3Arest_json)) it turned out to be such a hassle.

Now working on a way to generate a base64-encoded stream of HTML-fields and signing details to offer the REST-API of iTop.
I installed `hwcrypto.js` on the server. In Firefox I installed the [Firefox PKCS11 loader plugin](https://github.com/open-eid/firefox-pkcs11-loader) from ID. But I keep getting:

> Debug: hwcrypto.js 0.0.13 with failing backend No implementation getCertificate() failed: Error: no_implementation

Does someone know how to connect the hwcrypto.js to the physical card reader? Firefox sees it (Options - Advanced - Security Devices.